# Percona / MySQL audit log plugin - limiting the content?

Tags: mysql-5.5, audit

I've been looking to experiment with Perconas Audit Plugin, as it sounds like it could be potentially very useful. 
However it appears that it is a very blunt (ALL or NOTHING) tool.

From my perspective, I am simply interested in DDL statements (`CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP` etc).

Is there an way to limit what it logs, or is it really just ALL or NOTHING.

I fear I already know the answer, as I can't see any mention in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, from what I can tell, Percona Audit Log Plugin, has very little in the way of configuration.

I looked at McAfee Audit Plugin, but that doesn't seem to work on Debian MySQL.

I also looked at MariaDB Audit Plugin, and that seems to have some level of filtering (DDL or DML). 
Unfortunately it requires 5.5.42 , and most of my DBs are 5.5.40. Still, on my test system it seems to work.